# org-babel captions on results don't export to LaTeX?

Tags: org-export, org-babel

I hope the following complete minimal example is self-explanatory. It contains my question. It should run without error messages in org-babel. I looked at the six related suggested questions on the site and did not see a satisfactory answer.

```
#+CAPTION: The caption for this org-babel code block exports to /LaTeX/
#+name: elisp-prelude
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output :exports both
  (princ (concat (format "Emacs version: %s\n" (emacs-version))
                 (format "org version: %s\n" (org-version))))
#+END_SRC

#+CAPTION: But this caption for the results won't export to /LaTeX/
#+LABEL: res:elisp-prelude
#+RESULTS: elisp-prelude
: Emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1911))
:  of 2016-09-17
: org version: 9.0.6

The results are computed correctly each time I export to /LaTeX/, but the
caption for the results does not export.
What can I do to make the caption for the results display in the exported /LaTeX/?
```

**EDIT**: I tried adding a `#+NAME` header to the `#+RESULTS` block, both before and after the `#+LABEL`, but the results are the same: no export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding ":wrap SRC text" worked.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output :exports both :wrap SRC text
```